# What is ${Tmp0} in a sh script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, environment-variables, sh

In a shell script, I found the following line of code:

`rm -f "${Tmp0}"`

It is one of the first lines in the script, and I'm not familiar with the Tmp0 variable. Is it a shell standard mapping to something specific? I did some Google searches and I can't seem to find good explanation.

I suspect this is a leftover from a previous version of the script (no need to see the whole thing, it's irrelevant), since I can't see any reference to this variable anywhere else in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have predefined meaning, but that doesn't mean it's useless. If someone exports this variable before calling this script it will delete the defined file. Also if this script `source`s another file, this variable might be defined there.

Anyway, if none of the two conditions hold true, then it indeed might be a leftover.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I though as much but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard meaning for the variable `${Tmp0}`.

Usually, there'd be an assignment to `Tmp0` before that, such as:

```
Tmp0="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.$$.0"               # Generate a file name
rm -f "${Tmp0}"                               # Ensure file does not exist!
trap 'rm -f "${Tmp0}"; exit 1' 0 1 2 3 13 15  # Ensure file is cleaned up on early exit

...code using $Tmp0 as a temporary file...

rm -f "${Tmp0}"   # Clean up
trap 0            # Allow exit status other than 1
exit $status      # Exit with specified status
```

If the assignment isn't visible, then it is probably leftover debris of some sort, or someone's not very careful chosen environment variable naming scheme (and somewhat dubious handling of files; scripts that go around deleting files unconditionally are seldom popular for long).

Comment: That's what I thought. Was just making sure in case it was an old standard I didn't know about. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

That's **not a hard-coded variable** of the shell, if that's what you meant.

You can **add a simple debug** to the code to print the content of the variable and that information might give you some clues on it's purpose:

```
echo "DEBUG: Tmp0 content is: ${Tmp0}"
rm -f "${Tmp0}"
```